# Facebook login dialog will not work with UIAlertView, but does with UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, uialertview

I have this piece of code which I use for showing a login dialog/posting to the users wall:

```
_posting = YES;
// If we're not logged in, log in first...
if (![_session isConnected]) {
    self.loginDialog = nil;
    loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init]; 
    [_loginDialog show];
}
// If we have a session and a name, post to the wall!
else if (_facebookName != nil) {
    [self postToWall];
}
// Otherwise, we don't have a name yet, just wait for that to come through.
```

If I connect this code to a button, it works.  However, when I place it inside the following method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
    else
    {       
        _posting = YES;
        // If we're not logged in, log in first...
        if (![_session isConnected]) {
            self.loginDialog = nil;
            _loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init];    
            [_loginDialog show];
        }
        // If we have a session and a name, post to the wall!
        else if (_facebookName != nil) {
            [self postToWall];
        }
        // Otherwise, we don't have a name yet, just wait for that to come through.

    }
}
```

It doesn't work..

Can anyone explain as to why this might be?  When I say it doesn't work, I mean the dialog displays very briefly before closing itself.  The app doesn't crash.

Comment: Are you set deleagate of UIAlertview?

Comment: Yes I have, in the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, using the following line in the conditional instead of the facebook dialog code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showFBLoginDialog) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Seems you need to wait for the resources associated with the alert view to become available.

EDIT: The showFBLoginDialog method contains the dialog code that was originally in the conditional.

Answer (score 7):

The waiting 1 sec is not a solution and doesn't actually fixes the problem.

The problem is that you listen to:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Which should be:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Because at the `clickedButtonAtIndex` function the view isn't closed and this can cause problems.

Edit:
To make it work in iOS 4 add your facebook login call to a method and call the following function in the didDismissWithButtonIndex:

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(facebookOpenAction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: the did dismiss is a great solution, 10x a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue in iOS 5.

I don't see this as a solution, rather a quick fix/hack. Waiting for a 1 second delay may seem a little long, I wonder how low this delay can be set, the simulator shouldn't be used to asses this, and I no longer have a device running iOS 4. Would be interested to find out.

Maybe it would be better to add KVO to the alert view object to have a more precise idea of when it is destroyed, and trigger the dialog at that point.